# Docker-swarm >> Cannot connect to the docker engine endpoint

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

```
docker version 1.9.1
swarm version 1.0.1
```

why on connecting 3 VMs (bridged net) to swarm. "docker info" shows me all nodes

> > Status pending.

1 of 3 hosts is **manager** all output is from this host. I don't know where to look for.

On running `swarm --debug manage token://XXXXX`

output >>

```
*INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP addr=127.0.0.1:2375 proto=tcp

DEBU[0000] Failed to validate pending node: Cannot connect to the docker engine endpoint  Addr=10.32.1.38:2375

DEBU[0000] Failed to validate pending node: Cannot connect to the docker engine endpoint  Addr=10.32.1.4:2375

DEBU[0000] Failed to validate pending node: Cannot connect to the docker engine endpoint  Addr=10.32.1.33:2375
```

Then

```
root@ubuntu:~# ps -ef | grep swarm

root 2158  1391  0 12:28 pts/2 00:00:00 swarm join token://xxxxxxx --addr 10.32.1.4:2375

root 2407  1213  0 13:57 pts/1 00:00:00 swarm manage token://xxxxxxx -H 0.0.0.0:4243

root 2413  1391  0 13:57 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto swarm
```

Then

```
root@ubuntu:~# swarm list token://xxxxxxxxxxx

10.32.1.4:2375
10.32.1.33:2375
10.32.1.38:2375
```

Then

```
root@ubuntu:~# ps -ef | grep docker

root      2330     1  0 12:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/docker daemon

root      2421  1391  0 14:10 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto docker
```

heartbeat sorted - runs in background, checked ports, name resolution, pingable from manager.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **docker daemon** can listen on three different types of Socket: **unix**, **tcp** and **fd**.

By default, **docker daemon** just listen on unix socket.

If you need to access the Docker daemon remotely, you need to enable the tcp socket.

When creating docker swarm cluster, the swarm manager need to access the docker daemon of swarm agent nodes remotely.

Therefore, you need to re-configure the **docker daemon**

```
vim /etc/default/docker
```

Add following line:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

Restart **docker daemon**

```
sudo restart docker
```

By doing this, the **docker daemon** can be accessed remotely.

References:

1. [Docker document: docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/)
2. [Docker document: create a swarm for development](https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-manual/)

Answer (score 3):

I have added DOCKER_OPTS values in /etc/default/docker

**DOCKER_OPTS="-H <>host IP<>:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"**

to be more precise << Host IP >> is same host IP you editing your /etc/default/docker file.

Maybe it will help someone.

Comment: Depending on your environment, it it should be advisable to protect your daemon socket. https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/

Answer (score 3):

**Configuration methods differ depending on the host OS on which you're running Docker.**

See Docker Daemon configuration instructions *(scroll down to find your host OS)*:
[Docker Configuration Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/configuring/)

I'm running **Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2** : therefore I followed config instructions for my OS form the link above and did the following:

1. `mkdir /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d`
2. Create a docker.conf file
   `vi /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf`
3. Add the following to the docker.conf file then save.

   ```
   [Service]
   ExecStart=
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -D -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
   ```
4. Flush Changes

   ```
   systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
5. Restart Docker

   ```
   systemctl restart docker
   ```

The key line of configuration (and where I deviated slightly from the documentation) is:

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -D -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`

Let's go through this piece by piece:

- `/usr/bin/docker` start from the docker binary
- `daemon` start the Docker Daemon
- `-D` start in debug mode (not required)
- `-H unix:///var/run/docker.sock` creates the default Docker Socket
- `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` creates a tcp Docker Socket listening on port 2375 on all network interfaces

After making these changes, I restarted my docker swarm containers (and in my case my Consul containers as well) and ran `docker -H tcp://<IP_OF_SWARM_MASTER>:<PORT_YOU_TOLD_SWARM_MASTER_TO_LISTEN_ON> info` to see if I was no longer getting the `Cannot connect to the docker engine endpoint` error.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me by adding in swarm workers service config `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` where `ExecStart` is located this line:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
```

Flush changes and restart Docker:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker.service
```

But this approach is unprotected, need additional security configs.

Answer (score 1):

I tired the solutions mentioned in this thread. Editing /etc/default/docker did not work for me.

Finally what was the following solution.

Edit /lib/systemd/system/docker.service file
Find the line which starts with ExecStart and add -H=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 to make it look like

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H=fd:// -H=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
```

Save the Modified File
Reload the docker daemon

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Restart the container

```
sudo service docker restart
```

Test if it is working by using following command

```
curl http://localhost:2375/images/json
```

If everything is fine below command should return  a JSON.

To test remotely, use the PC name or IP address of Docker Host.